# Primefaces mobile view navigation with Spring: view does not change

Tags: spring, mobile, primefaces

I'm implementing a questionnaire in Spring 3.2.0, Spring webflow, JSF 2.1.11, Primefaces 3.4.1, Primefaces mobile 0.9.3

The specification is to have all the question in a same physic .xhtml page but separated into sections, so that only one section displays at a time. In the mobile website I use a pm:view for every section.

I need to use post navigation because all the section refers to the same bean to submit data and I need to validate after every section is filled. Here's an example of my code:

```
<pm:page id="page">

      <pm:view id="page1">
         <pm:content>
            <h:form id="page1Form">
                <h:panelGroup id="form1Container" >
                    <p:inputText id="input1" value="${managedBean.property1}" required="true" />

                    <p:commandButton  id="next" action="pm:page2" value="Next" process="form1Container" update="form1Container :page2Form"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
         </pm:content>
      </pm:view>   

      <pm:view id="page2">
         <pm:content>
            <h:form id="page2Form">
                <h:panelGroup id="form2Container" >
                    <p:inputText id="input2" value="${managedBean.property2}" required="true" />

                    <h:commandButton id="registerSave" action="save" value="Save"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
         </pm:content>
      </pm:view>   

</pm:page>
```

The validation fires correctly and the value of input1 is updated on press of the "next" button". Also I can see an ajax request on the server logs. However The page just refresh remaining on page1, page2 is never displayed. There are no validation errors in the page and I can see with firebugs that there were no errors in the request/response.

What I'm doing wrong to reach page2?

I can see that the content of page2 is hidden with css in the generated html page, I could try using javascript to make it visible but all the css classes are missing from the html (I think jQuery does that for performances). There's a way I could use javascript as a workaround of this issue?

Thanks again,

Mattia

p.s. I also tried with ajax="false" in the "next" button but it still doesn't work. I tried also to put the action string as return object of a bean method, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround in the old Primefaces mobile navigation style. On the ajax command button I call directly PrimeFaces.navigate, checking before for validation errors. The code is like this:

```
<p:commandButton  id="nextButton_page1" action="pm:page2" oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) PrimeFaces.navigate('#page2',{});" value="Next" process="form1Container" update="form1Container :page2Form"/>
```

Similar thing for the previous button. This works for me: the ajax call process the values of form1, the navigation stop if any validation errors occur or it goes to page2 if everything is fine.

if (!args.validationFailed) checks for validation errors

PrimeFaces.navigate('#page2',{}) navigate to the next page

Have a good day,

Mattia